# Ink usage of white text background

Tags: floats, color, backgrounds, printing

I am working on a project that contains a lot of colorboxes and floats with background color. This consumes a lot of ink, which makes me consider making a separate copy available that uses transparent backgrounds.

The simplest option would be to replace all background color definitions with `{gray}{1}` (which yields what we percieve as ‘white’/‘transparent’ on computer screens), but I wonder if LaTeX is smart enough to figure out for printed copies that it doesn’t need to color that at all, as paper is already white.

Which of the paragraphs 2-4 below use white ink, if any? (analogue `{gray}{0.95}` paragraphs 5-7 included for clarity)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{white}{gray}{1}
\definecolor{gray}{gray}{0.95}
\begin{document}

1. black text on default background

2. \textcolor{white}{white text on default background}

3. \colorbox{white}{black text on white background}

4. \colorbox{white}{\textcolor{white}{white text on white background}}

5. \textcolor{gray}{gray text on default background}

6. \colorbox{gray}{black text on gray background}

7. \colorbox{gray}{\textcolor{gray}{gray text on gray background}}

\end{document}
```

[image: generated pdf output]

Comment: Unless you have white ink in your printer, what makes you think *any* of these use white ink? Mixing coloured inks is not like mixing light - you don't get white if you just keep adding everything. To get white, you have to not add it in the first place. If you print white text onto a coloured sheet of paper, can you see it?

Comment: LaTeX knows nothing about printing or ink or what your printer does or how to turn things into a stream of data to send to your device. That is the job of other software. It is not managed by your TeX installation at all. (Exception: if you are on Windows and your editor/viewer is part of your TeX distribution, *maybe* that's different. I know zilch about printing on Windows. But it still isn't LaTeX or TeX proper - that would be a special Windows-thing.)

Comment: You could use \def\black{white} and \def\white{black} ;-)